# Is there a way to set a semi-transparent background on Google Slides when using a picture as the background image? (not opaque or transparent)

Tags: google, google-slides

Without being able to select a translucency level the words get lost on the Google Slide presentation. Is there a way to use pictures that shoe the theme of the slide without this happening? There was one answer that demonstrated how to do this with solid coulours but not with photos. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you have tried; if you don't know what to try, please look at the Google Slides user interface, especially the menus and toolbar buttons. Try using the Help menu.

Comment: "There was one answer that demonstrated how to do this with solid coulours but not with photos" wouldn't hurt to add a link

Comment: Please [edit] the question to better clarify the problem.  For example, you could explain specifically what you are trying to do using the language of the application (what menu, what option, etc.), provide a link to the example you referred to, include an example screenshot showing the words getting lost, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, kind of. Just add an image and duplicate the slide. That's the only way I can think ot setting a semi-transparent background on Google Slides with a picture as the background image.

Once the picture is added:

- Click on “Format Options”.
- In the new window pane that opens on the right, click on “Adjustments”.
- Modify the “Opacity” slider until the result is achieved.

You can also set a diferent background color to make it looks nicer and should help you use pictures that show the theme of the slide without losing the words on the Google Slide presentation.

Here's an example:

[image]